# html parsing in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, html-parsing

I need to parse an html so any one tell me how to do this in objective-c?

Comment: What is your target: Mac OS or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Try [HTMLKit](https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit). It is a pure Objective-C HTML parser with CSS3 Selectors support. It is not a wrapper around libxml or any other library, but rather a complete WHATWG HTML specification-compliant implementation.

Here are some examples in Swift:

```
let htmlString = "<div><h1>HTMLKit</h1><p>Hello there!</p></div>"
let document = HTMLDocument(string: htmlString)

let stuff = HTMLElement(tagName:"ul", attributes: ["class": "list"])
stuff.innerHTML = "<li>item 1<li>item 2"

let body = document.body!
body.appendNode(stuff)

let items = document.querySelectorAll(".list li")
```